# OpenGL running in Visual C++ 2010 Express - identifier not found

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, opengl

I´m trying to compile the code below for the start of a OpenGL class and the build fails. What can I do to correct this? Is it something to do with the linker?

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>


//Drawing funciton
void draw(void)
{
    //Background color
    glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    //Draw order
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glFlush();
}

//Main program
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    //Simple buffer
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,400);
    glutCreateWindow("Red window");
    //Call to the drawing function
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want us to *guess* where the error "identifier not found" is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See tutorial here: http://openglbook.com/setting-up-opengl-glew-and-freeglut-in-visual-c/

you will have to include "glut.h"

and add additional libraries reference: opengl32.lib and freeglut.lib

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

[Reference](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node7.html).